# Why would it give JSON.stringfy error, even when I have not used it?

Tags: nestjs, stringify

I am building application in nodejs where I have to display the data by hitting the HTTPS endpoint. I am using Swagger UI to display the data. I am getting following error

```
Converting circular structure to JSON +1169ms
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1123:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (node_modules/express/lib/response.js:260:14)
    at ExpressAdapter.reply (node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/adapters/express-adapter.js:23:57)
    at RouterResponseController.apply (node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-response-controller.js:10:36)
    at @nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:163:48
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

even when I have `not used JSON.stringfy` in my code. How can I resolve this error?
Here is my controller.ts code

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Controller('/service/api/message')
export class MessageController {

  source: string;
  productCode: string;
  vehicleType: string;
  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}
@Post()
  @ApiUseTags('processor-dispatcher')
  @ApiOperation({ title: 'Generate product message for the SNS topics' })
  async generateMessage(@Body() productEvent: ProductEvent) {

    return this.messageService
      .getData(this.source, this.productCode, this.vehicleType)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }
}
```

Here is my service.ts

```
import Axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}

  configEndPoint: string =
    'https:www.xyz.com';


  getData(
    source: string,
    productCode: string,
    vehicleType: string,
  ): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpService.get(this.configEndPoint, { validateStatus: null });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be `subscribing` to the observable, NestJS will handle that under the hood, just return the unsubscribed observable to the controller and let Nest handle it.

The reason you are getting a `JSON.stringify` error, even though *you* aren't using it, is because `express` is using it under the hood in its `send` method. The `AxiosResponse` type (what the `HttpService` returns), has circular references to itself, so you need to not send the full response (it's a bad practice to return that entire response anyways, too much extra data). What you can do instead is use the `map` operator in a `pipe` to map which parts of the res you want to send back. Example

```js
@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}

  configEndPoint: string =
    'https:www.xyz.com';


  getData(
    source: string,
    productCode: string,
    vehicleType: string,
  ): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpService.get(this.configEndPoint, { validateStatus: null }).pipe(
      map(res => res.data)
    );
  }
}
```

This will get the `data` property of the `AxiosResponse` and allow to only send that back.

Comment: Okay, and how and where can I just specify which data from endpoint do I require?

Comment: What do you mean? You're deciding what endpoint you are calling. You should look at what API you are consuming and what it's return looks like. The `data` property is just what the consumed endpoint returns, what that looks like depends on what the API is and how it was developed

Comment: I get your point, I wanted to know if endpoint contains array of JSON data then where should I modify my code to get 1st array data?

Comment: When did we start talking about arrays of data? The returned structure is a JSON, the `data` property _could_ be an array, depending on the return of the endpoint, but that's not guaranteed. If you are talking about receiving multiple responses, that shouldn't happen unless you make multiple callouts